# Browser back button from Django page to React page renders raw JSON

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, browser

I have an app with one single page react app but other pages are Django templates. For example I have a react dashboard which has buttons that take you to different django templates (pages) This  works fine until I use the browser back button to go to react dashboard and it just gives me raw json data.

[image]

But as soon as I hit refresh it loads the DOM

So first I though I ll use performance.navigation.type === 2 in the useEffect and just reload from there but the useEffect is not even getting called.

I did try some stack overflow answers but most of them answer how to handle back button when you are routing with in a react app.

Any solution would be appreciated. Ty

Comment: If you post a working demo with code it would be easier for people to help you.

Comment: There is something wrong in your router, post relevant code first

Comment: @BernardoMarques Sorry can't post the code cuz of some reasons. But the way it works is there is a get request that the react makes to django for it to load and that works fine.. but on hitting browser back react is not loading but get is still called and the raw JSON is shown in the browser.

Comment: @MarioNikolaus By router do you mean react router ?

Comment: Why can't you post the code?

Comment: @JMadelaine Company data

Comment: It is difficult to tell you what the problem is if you don't show us what the problem is. There could be many reasons. You don't have to post any company data, just use test data and create a reproducible example.

Comment: @JMadelaine Alright will mimic the flow and reopen this question! Thank you

Comment: @DaminiGanesh it could be either server routing or django routing, it is difficult to say without any code

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am facing the exact same issue. When using browser back or forward buttons, raw JSON data from my GET request is loaded, but the React component isn't, until I hit refresh. If I access the route through the links in the website all is fine, only breaks when using browser back or forward buttons. Almost like the data is being received but the React component isn't being triggered/mounted/rendered.